# Звонки в Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Итак, представьте себе ситуацию, в приложении имеется 3 страницы:

Home->Section->Phones

Выше написаны переходы по этим страницам(из Home в Section, из Section в Phones).

Проблема в том что при попытке вызова звонка в Phones странице приложение просто закрывается, при вызове в Home или Section - все работает нормально. В чем может быть проблема?(не возможно вызвать звонок на третей вложенной странице приложения(любой))
Вызываю звонок так:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.ShowPhoneCallUI(телефон, имя);
```

Может быть я передаю слишком сложный объект между страницами? Возможно надо передавать простые переменные??

Comment: Какие-либо дополнительные данные нужны. Например коды ошибок, статусы, исключения, сообщения и прочее. Что происходит в отладчике?

Comment: @Cerbo, суть в том что через Visual Studio если запускать то ничего не крашится, все хорошо, если через телефон уже собранное то тогда крашится. Создавал в Release/Debug режимах.

Comment: То есть на эмуляторе под отладчиком работает, а на трубке нет?

Comment: @Cerbo, когда я запускаю сбилженое уже(не из Visual Studio) то тогда крашится, если запускать через Visual Studio(когда я разрабатываю) то все ок

Comment: После падения данные какие-либо остаются? Дамп например.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В общем, в который раз создаю вопрос и пока жду на него ответ сам решаю, все было достаточно просто, я передавал через `NavigationState` не сериализированные данные (не преобразованные к простому формату, например строке). Сериализация на передаче, и десериализация на приеме (в новой странице) решила данную проблему.

Сериализация:

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Frame.Navigate(typeof(Views.Taxi.Cities.First), JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e.ClickedItem as StaticFBusesData)))
    {
        throw new Exception(this.resourceLoader.GetString("NavigationFailedExceptionMessage"));
    }
}
```

Десериализация:

```
private async void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    if (!isLoaded)
    {
        StaticFBusesData param = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StaticFBusesData>(e.NavigationParameter.ToString());
    }
}
```

Использовал Newtonsoft.Json библиотеку для работы с Json

Comment: Пожалуйста, подробнее поясните что куда вы передавали и сериализовывали. Желательно с кодом.

Comment: @Cerbo, описал принцип